# 405 Error: The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: html, flask, app-config, http-status-code-405, reset-password

I've been trying to code the reset password for my website. However, I keep on running into the 405 error. Google says it's probable that it is a client side error, but I think my html is fine. I'm not sure what else can be causing the error.

I've tried testing the url without the content, but that has not been working either.

**routes.py**

```
def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token()
    msg = Message('Password Reset Request', sender='noreply@clubsapp.com', recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f'''To reset your password, visit the following link:
{url_for('reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}

If you did not make this request then simply ignore this email and no change will be made.
'''
    mail.send(msg)

@users.route('/reset_request', methods=['GET, POST'])
def reset_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    form = RequestResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        send_reset_email(user)
        flash('An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
    return render_template('reset_request.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)

@users.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods=['GET, POST'])
def reset_token(token):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    user = User.verify_reset_token(token)
    if user is None:
        flash('That is an invalid or expired token', 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('reset_request'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user.password = hashed_password
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Your password has been updated, you are now able to log in!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
    return render_template('reset_token.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RequestResetForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()],
        render_kw={"placeholder":"Enter Email"})
    submit = SubmitField('Request Password Reset')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()     
        if user is None:
            raise ValidationError('There is no account with that email. You must register first.')

class ResetPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('confirm_password', message='Passwords Must Match')],
        render_kw={"placeholder":"Create Password"})
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password', message='Passwords Must Match')],
        render_kw={"placeholder":"Confirm Password"})
    submit = SubmitField('Reset Password')
```

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=ROLES['student'])
    clubs = db.relationship('Club', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id})

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Login</legend>
            ...(irrelevant content)
<div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
        <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('users.register') }}">Don't Have An Account?</a>
    </small>
    <small class="text-muted ml-2">
        <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('users.reset_request') }}">Forgot Password?</a>
    </small>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant line from the Flask logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple error. It is not `methods=['GET, POST']`.

Change  to

```
methods=['GET', 'POST']
```

[Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

> **HTTP Methods**
>
> Web applications use different HTTP methods when accessing URLs. You
>   should familiarize yourself with the HTTP methods as you work with
>   Flask. By default, a route only answers to GET requests. You can use
>   the methods argument of the route() decorator to handle different HTTP
>   methods.
>
> ```
> from flask import request
>
> @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
> def login():
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         return do_the_login()
>     else:
>         return show_the_login_form()
> ```